# How to make my page responsive to SF1?

Tags: visualforce

I could use some help or guidance making my page responsive to SF1. I am not much of a coder, but I was able to get my VF page up and running (very basic). Is it that much more difficult to make this very basic VF page responsive to SF1?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div align="center">
        <apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01536000001W5Ct" style="vertical-align:right" width="150" height="50"/>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;">
        <apex:outputText value="Customer Inventory Review Screen" /> 
    </div>
    <flow:interview name="Customer_Audit_Portal_SF1" finishLocation="/{!Account.Id}">            
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Using a whole bunch of `<br>` tags probably won't help. I'm not sure how much you can do to a `<flow:interview>` though.